# Droid only boots into ClockwordMod

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, motorola-droid, rom-manager

So I've just rooted my Motorola Droid (I've done this before on the same device, but with a different method back on 2.0.1). I am on 2.2.2.

The root went successfully, Super User app was present, etc.  I then installed ROM Manager and http://www.cyanogenmod.com/ from my SD card.

After that, my phone would boot, then run through the boot animation, freeze, then start the boot animation over again, and repeat.

I made a backup through ROM Manager before the install, and have restored it.

From what I could tell, that went fine, but now I'm stuck in ClockwordMod Recovery each time I try to reboot my device.

It boots once, showing the Motorola logo, then shuts off, then boots again showing the logo, then goes directly into ClockworkMod, without me holding `x` or anything special.

Can I get out of this or am I bricked?  And troubleshooting suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Restoring a backup of one ROM over top of a different ROM is a bad idea; although it may work in some cases, the device partitions often get screwed up.  You need to flash a working ROM -- preferably the original one -- and should have no problems doing so since you have Clockwork access.

Comment: Where can I find a 'working' ROM?